# Помогите определиться с составом предложения

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор, члены-предложения

Каким членом является слово «правда» в начале и в конце предложения «Если это правда, нет ни одной травинки счастливее меня, но правда ли это?»

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Если это правда, нет ни одной травинки счастливее меня, но правда ли это?*

Если это правда = если это является правдой. Правда -составное именное сказуемое.

...но правда ли это? = но является ли это правдой? Правда - сказуемое. Так что и в начале предложения, и в конце - сказуемое, а это - подлежащее.